# El proceso no puede obtener acceso al archivo porque está siendo utilizado en otro proceso

Tags: c#, sql, .net

les pido me puedan echar una manito, tengo el siguiente código en una aplicación .exe que es invocada desde SQL mediante comando xp_cmdshell, el error que me arroja al invocar varias veces a la vez es: "El proceso no puede obtener acceso al archivo porque está siendo utilizado en otro proceso.  FileStream" esto por que el .exe está escribiendo en el archivo de texto.

Lo que necesito es que si se cae por este error, que no escriba en el log eso da lo mismo, pero que el programa se siga ejecutando:

Otro alternativa es si existe algún comando que identifique el archivo de texto está siendo utilizado, de esta forma el proceso debiera esperar hasta que este esté libre.

```
        /// </summary>
        private static void Log(String File_Log, String mensaje)
        {
            FileStream fs = null; StreamWriter sw = null;
            try
            {
                fs = new FileStream(File_Log, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
                sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
                sw.WriteLine(GetToken() + ": " + mensaje);
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (sw != null) sw.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez el problema sea que estás utilizando *sw.Close();* y no [*sw.Dispose();*](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose) y por lo tanto, no se estén liberando los recursos adecuadamente.

Yo este tipo de funciones las suelo escribir dentro de un *[using(){}](https://www.variablenotfound.com/2009/02/usando-using-valga-la-redundancia-c.html#recursos)*

*Algo parecido a esto debería de funcionar:*

```
    private static void Log(String File_Log, String mensaje)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(File_Log, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)) 
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                try
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(GetToken() + ": " + mensaje);
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Nota: No sé en que forma estás llamando al método Log() pero si lo estás haciendo en un bucle, o lo estás llamando bastantes veces en un corto periodo de tiempo, tal vez te interese almacenar la información en una variable o buffer y cada X tiempo llamar a Log() para guardar la información en el archivo.